# Scale vuforia camera render in cardboard stereoscreen

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

trying to integrate vuforia 4.2 and cardboard in Unity 5.1. Everything works except for field of view. Can not modify vuforia camera, it breaks matching between 3d object and videobackground, so I need to scale it in cardboard somewhere. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here. Please explain more on your question.

Comment: In few words, I need to scale image from vuforia camera to fill all the area(no white spots)

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the field of view of the AR cameras, the problem if you match the cardboard size, it will zoom in too much for your brain to adapt, so you get dizzy and headaches. You need to play with those fields in order to get the best of all.